# Craft 2: What would prevent most cached template chunks from showing up in the `templatecaches` table?

Tags: cache, craft2

I am working on a Craft 2 site that is exhibiting some rather poor performance characteristics.

On production, we use memcache for caching, and monitoring on the server shows disappointing cache hit ratios on the memcache server - typically ~10% for the first while after a manual cache clear, rising to and stabilizing near 80% after a few days. Given that traffic is concentrated on a handful of pages, this is not the profile we would expect.

To confirm this, I have been doing some testing on my local using the `db` cache method, and I am seeing a similar profile. For instance, on a category page, we have the following cached elements:

1. A list of sub categories
2. A list of articles within this category
3. A list of related events
4. A list of people related to this category

Each of these is cached. The `{% cache %}`/`{% endcache %}` block for each of these contains both the `craft.entries` or `craft.categories` queries used to fetch the content as well as the Twig code to generate the markup.

However, on a page load, only the list of subcategories gets populated in the `templatecaches` database table, with corresponding criteria in `templatecachecriteria`.

This patterns is repeated on all pages of the site, where only one or two cached chunks will actually get stored in the cache, leading to a local cache hit ratio in line with what we are seeing on production.

The bottom line question is this: What would cause Craft to not store the contents of a `{% cache %}`/`{% endcache %}` block?

Edit: Here is a copy of the category template described above:

```
{% extends "_layout" %}

{% set title = category.title %}
{% set heroImage = category.heroImage.first ?? null %}


{% block content %}
  <article>
    <header>
      {% if heroImage %}
        {% include '_shared/hero' with { showAttribution: false } %}
      {% endif %}

      <div class="article__header {% if heroImage %}-overlap{% endif %} -blue wrapper -extra-large">

        {% include '_shared/image-attribution' %}

        {% if category.level > 1 %}
          <p class="overlap-label margin-bottom">
            <span class="overlap-label__underline">Part of</span>
            <a href="{{ category.parent.url }}">
              <span class="chevron -left -gray"></span>
              {{ category.parent }}
            </a>
          </p>
        {% endif %}

        {% cache globally using key category.title ~ ':subCategories'%}
        <h1 class="page-title">{{ category.title }}</h1>
        {% set subCategories = craft.categories({
        group: 'researchArea',
        descendantOf: category,
        descendantDist: 1
        }) %}
        {% if subCategories | length and category.level < 3 %}
          <p class="overlap-label margin-top">
            <span class="overlap-label__underline">Within {{ category.title }}</span>
          </p>

          {% include '_shared/category-list-columns' with { categories: subCategories } %}
        {% endif %}
        {% endcache %}
      </div>
    </header>

    {% if category.level == 1 %}
      <div class="wrapper wysiwyg margin-vertical">
        {% if category.categoryDescription | length %}
          <p>{{ category.categoryDescription }}</p>
        {% endif %}
      </div>

      <p class="center"><a href="{{ general.donationPage }}" class="button -solid">Support ACME</a></p>
    {% endif %}

    {% if category.featuredPublications | length %}
      <section class="featured-block margin-vertical-2x">
        <h2 class="featured-block__title">Highlights</h2>

        {% include '_shared/featured-listing' with { entries: category.featuredPublications } %}
      </section>
    {% endif %}

    {% if category.level == 2 %}
      <div class="wrapper wysiwyg margin-vertical">
        {% if category.categoryDescription | length %}
          <p>{{ category.categoryDescription }}</p>
        {% endif %}

        <p class="center margin-vertical-2x"><a href="{{ general.donationPage }}" class="button -solid">Support ACME</a></p>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  </article>

  {% cache globally using key category.title ~ ':recentPublications' %}
  {% set recentPublications = craft.entries({
  relatedTo: category,
  section: ['reports', 'articlesMultimedia'],
  limit: 5,
  with: [
  'heroImage',
  'titleImage',
  'associatedPeople',
  'source'
  ]
  }) %}
  {% if recentPublications | length %}
    <section class="wrapper -extra-large margin-vertical-2x">
      <h2 class="section-title margin-bottom-half-em">Recent Publications</h2>

      <div class="wrapper">
          {% include '_shared/entry-listing' with { entries: recentPublications } %}
        <p class="margin-top-1em">
          <a href="/reports?area={{ category.slug }}" class="button">View All Reports</a>
          <a href="/articles-multimedia?area={{ category.slug }}" class="button">View All Articles & Multimedia</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
  {% endif %}
  {% endcache %}

  {% cache globally using key category.title ~ ':relatedEvents'%}
    {% set relatedEvents = craft.entries({
    relatedTo: category,
    section: 'events',
    limit: 3,
    with: [
    'heroImage',
    'researchAreas'
    ]
    }) %}
    {% if relatedEvents | length %}
      <section class="wrapper -extra-large margin-vertical-2x">
        <h2 class="section-title margin-bottom-half-em">Related Events</h2>

        <div class="wrapper -extra-large">
            {% include '_shared/blocks/photoListingMultiple' with {
              featuredEntries: relatedEvents,
              columns: '3'
            } %}
          <p class="margin-top-1em">
            <a href="/events?area={{ category.slug }}" class="button">View All Events</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>
    {% endif %}
  {% endcache %}


  {% cache globally using key category.title ~ ':researchTeam'%}
    {% set researchTeam = craft.entries({
    relatedTo: category,
    section: 'people',
    limit: category.level == 1 ? 15 : 10,
    with: [
    'thumbnailImage'
    ]
    }) %}
    {% if researchTeam | length %}
      <section class="wrapper -extra-large margin-vertical-2x">
        <h2 class="section-title margin-bottom-half-em">Research Team</h2>

        <div class="wrapper -large">
          <ul class="person-list">
              {% for person in researchTeam %}
                <li>
                  {% set image = person.thumbnailImage[0] ?? null %}

                  {% if image %}
                    <img
                      src="{{ img.spacer }}"
                      srcset="{{ image.url({ width: 120 }) }} 1x,
                              {{ image.url({ width: 240 }) }} 2x"
                      width="120"
                      height="120"
                      class="desaturate"
                      alt="">
                  {% else %}
                    <img src="/assets/images/thumbnail.jpg" width="120" height="120" alt="">
                  {% endif %}

                  <h3 class="h4 margin-vertical-half-em person-list__name">
                    <a href="{{ person.url }}">{{ person.title }}</a>
                  </h3>

                  {% if person.personsTitle or person.personsAffiliation %}
                    <p class="person-list__title">{{ person.personsTitle }}{% if person.personsTitle and person.personsAffiliation %}, {% endif %}{{ person.personsAffiliation }}</p>
                  {% endif %}

                </li>
              {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>
    {% endif %}
  {% endcache %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

It turns our the image transforms weren't generating as the 'Generating Pending Image Transforms' task would get stuck. I pushed the task through by restarting, and the cache hit ratio went to 98-99%.

I've installed Imagemagick to hopefully help the transforms task to be more successful going forward.